# can't print a string after m.run() in python in kivy framework

Tags: python, oop, kivy

I want to `print('hello')` after running the `m.run()` but IDLE just shows me the result of `m.run` and it does not print the hello. How can I print a string after `m.run()`?

This is an example of my problem:

```
import socket
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class me (App):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.b=Button(text='button')
        self.g=GridLayout(cols=4)
        self.l=Label(text='label')
        self.t=TextInput(text='Type here your message: ')
        self.g.add_widget(self.b)
        self.g.add_widget(self.t)
        self.g.add_widget(self.l) 
    def build(self):
            return self.g

m=me()

m.run()

print('hello')
```

Comment: I don't have any experience with Kivy, but I suppose the `.run` method is analogous to `.mainloop` of tkinter, where the app enters its loop. This is how all gui apps work, in the sense, they enter a loop where they look out for user interaction and perform tasks based on the events that happen within the app.. whatever has to happen while the app is being run would have to be mentioned before calling the main loop, here - the `.run` method.. and whatever is written after the run method would be executed only after the window is closed.. kindly correct me if i am wrong

Comment: missed out on one thing that.. the usual way to exit that loop and look forward to what code is written after the run command would be to exit the gui in some way

Comment: Your code will execute the `print` after `m.run()`, but be aware that `m.run()` will not return until the `m` `App` completes (is closed), so the `print` will not be executed until the `App` is closed.